# How to programatically pause spotify when a call comes in on skype

Tags: python, skype, spotify

Skype has an inbuilt function where iTunes playback is paused and resumed automatically when a call comes in. It would be nice to have something similar for Spotify. Both provide a python API so this would seem the obvious route to go down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a stab at doing this in python. It runs in the background as a daemon, pausing/resuming spotify when a call comes. It uses the Python libraries for Skype & Spotify:

http://code.google.com/p/pytify/
https://developer.skype.com/wiki/Skype4Py

```
import Skype4Py
import time
from pytify import Spotify

# Create Skype object
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()

# Create Spotify object
spotify = Spotify()
spotifyPlaying = spotify.isPlaying()

# Create handler for when Skype call status changes
def on_call_status(call, status):
  if status == Skype4Py.clsInProgress:
    # Save current spotify state
    global spotifyPlaying
    spotifyPlaying = spotify.isPlaying()

    if spotify.isPlaying():
      print "Call started, pausing spotify"
      # Call started, pause Spotify
      spotify.stop()

  elif status == Skype4Py.clsFinished:
    # Call finished, resume Spotify if it was playing
    if spotifyPlaying and not spotify.isPlaying():
      print "Call finished, resuming spotify"
      spotify.playpause()  

skype.OnCallStatus = on_call_status

while True:
  time.sleep(10)
```